# Unable to start scan on Azure Purview for Azure Synapse Analytics Serverless Pool

Tags: serverless, azure-synapse, azure-purview

I have

1. Azure Synapse Workspace/Analytics setup ( that has built-in serverless pool)
2. Have Purview account ([Orange-account]) , in which having Purview Studio acccess
3. I have registered my Synapse Analytics on Purview Studio
4. I have created database mango in serverless pool
5. I have granted "Synapse Administrator" access to the [Orange-account]( in Synapse workspace)
6. Executed this from mango database
   CREATE USER [Orange-account] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
7. Executed this from master database
   EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', [Orange-account]

I am trying to initiate a Scan - so that I could fetch all meta data information from Azure Synapse Serverless pool database mango. But I am unable to create the scan event - as it gives permission issue.

Sharing more details with snapshot below

1. Snapshot of Sources tab in Purview Studio looks as below

[image]

2. I dont see any database listed in the "Database Name" drop down
   [image]
3. I entered the database manually and tried "Test Connection" ; that ends up with
   Error: (3867) Failed to access the Azure SQL data warehouse. The given credential has not been applied or does not have permission on the target database.Learn more
   
   [image]

What else can be causing this access issue here?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? It still does not work for me.

Comment: no luck yet. still not working

Answer (score 1):

At ths time the only the dedicated pools is supported . Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/purview-connector-overview) . Working is in progress for supporting serverless also.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-synapse-workspace says that "Azure Synapse Workspace scans support capturing metadata and schema for dedicated and serverless SQL databases within them. It also classifies the data automatically based on system and custom classification rules.". Yet it still does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

The latest docs recommend the following...

"Add the Azure Purview account MSI (represented by the account name) as sysadmin on the serverless SQL databases by running the command below in your SQL script:"

```
CREATE LOGIN [PurviewAccountName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER [PurviewAccountName];
```

More info here: [Using Managed identity for Serverless SQL databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-synapse-workspace#using-managed-identity-for-serverless-sql-databases)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this link and have gotten a successful scan:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-synapse-analytics

You might want to check that

1. You have assigned Purview MSI to Reader in both Synapse
2. You have assigned Purview MSI as Blob Storage Reader at the Storage resource
3. You have created the user/login for Purview MSI and added it to db_reader on your dedicated/serverless pool

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to grant your Purview account read access first.
[image]